# The jewish Q.E.D

Tags: words

What would be an equivalent to [Q.E.D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.) in the jargon of Halacha literature? Usually in the Gemara we something like: קא משמע לן, however I can't think of a word that is used as Q.E.D.

Maybe [הלמ״מ](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%97%D7%94%3A%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99) would be a good candidate or יצתה בת קול ואמרה?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya 0x90! Questions about the Hebrew language that aren't about Judaism itself are generally considered off topic, so this will likely be closed. There's no problem with that, however.

Comment: 'Hebrew language' is an example of linguistic rather than religious questions. The same would apply to Aramaic, Yiddish, Ladino, etc.

Comment: I've edited this question to be explicitly about the jargon of Halacha, in particular, consistent with 0x90's earlier comments and with the title of the question. As such, it's about the language of Judaism, and IMO, on-topic. If I see four other votes to re-open, I'll re-open.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, make it three, not four, as I agree.

Comment: I, too, agree that the edit makes this on-topic.  With three moderators saying yes, I'm going to go ahead and reopen.

Comment: Perhaps ודו״ק (whatever that means)

Comment: @DoubleAA what's it? reference?

Answer (score 3):

שמע מינה and קא משמע לן are used that way but both can also be used to introduce the conclusion rather than end the train of thought.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen any research on this, but maybe
**דו"ק**.

ודו"ק.

Comment: What does דו״ק stand for?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I was told "דוק וקל." It is used as the conclusion of a nuanced point.

Comment: @0x90 According to the [Acaademy of Hebrew Language](http://hebrew-academy.org.il/2010/03/25/%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A7/) it comes from Aramaic and is the same root as דקדק. I've always translated it as QED in my head.

Comment: @PopularIsn'tRight I would expect it to be from ד.י.ק

Answer (score 1):

מאי קא משמע לן and קא משמע לן seem to fit the description provided in the Wikipedia link above.

Comment: The only difference is that Q.E.D appears in the end.

Comment: @0x90 so does  קא משמע לן

Comment: there are dozens of examples throughout gemara, such as here in BB 17b בא בידים איצטריכא ליה, ס"ד אמינא: כיון דבא בידים ליבעי נמי רווחא טפי, קא משמע לן.

Comment: Yes, but not always. Could be also: "What does one try to say?"

Comment: קא משמע לן normally comes to indicate that the previous possibility is **rejected**, very different to QED.

Comment: @0x90 Appearing at the end isn't something you can duplicate naturally. Like how in Tanakh it says וידבר משה but in English we don't say And Spoke Moses